# UILabel subclass not showing when using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, constraints

I've created a subclass to manage my Theme but is not showing neither on device or simulator.

Here my `Header.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Header: UILabel {
    override var textColor: UIColor! {
        // White Color
        get { return ThemeManager.currentTheme.palette.primary }
        set {}
    }

    override var font: UIFont! {
        get { return ThemeManager.currentTheme.textStyle.headerText }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Here the implementation: (inside the viewcontroller)

```
var titleLabel: Header = Header()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .black

    // Background Image over the view
    setupBackground()

    setupStartButton()
    setupTitleLabel()

    print(titleLabel.frame)
}

// MARK: - Header
private func setupTitleLabel() {
    titleLabel.text = "0.0m"

    // titleLabel.font = ThemeManager.currentTheme.textStyle.headerText
    // titleLabel.textColor = ThemeManager.currentTheme.palette.primary

    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(titleLabel)

    setupTitleLabelAutolayout()
}


private func setupTitleLabelAutolayout() {
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    ])
}
```

But if I use `UILabel` instead of `Header` it works perfectly as expected.
I've also tried to implement `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `init(frame: CGRect)` but nothing changed.

If I set a `frame` on init then shows the text, but not styled and ignoring my constraints.

Surely I'm missing something, but what?

To avoid usefulness answers, here some infos:

- The `UILabel` textColor is white
- The background is black and has an image over it.
- I've tried to remove the image and all the stuff around except for the label and nothing changed.

Comment: By the way I have no storyboards.

Comment: Did you try to debug your UI hierarchy?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a poor reason to use subclassing. It doesn't allow you to mix-and-match when appropriate.

Better would be to make an extension:

```
extension UILabel {
    func withHeaderStyle() -> UILabel {
        self.textColor = ThemeManager.currentTheme.palette.primary
        self.font = ThemeManager.currentTheme.textStyle.headerText
        return self
    }
}
```

Then at point of use:

```
var titleLabel = UILabel().withHeaderStyle()
```

You can make several of these "withXStyle" methods and at the point of use you can chain them together. That's something you can't do with inheritance.

---

In general you should only use inherence when you want to *change behavior*. It's ill suited for changing data.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed that by editing the `Header` to this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Header: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupStyle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupStyle()
    }

    private func setupStyle() {
        self.textColor = ThemeManager.currentTheme.palette.primary
        self.font = ThemeManager.currentTheme.textStyle.headerText
    }
}
```

Basically if I understood right, when I set the `getter` in the label it doesn't (if you think about, it's quite obvious) anything.

I still think that there are better solutions, but this works fine for me so, I'll keep that.

Now you may ask: "Why did you overwritten the getter instead of doing this?"

It's the right question, and the right answer is that I read it in a swift article on medium, so I tought it was right.

PS: I've also tried with `didSet` but it obviously loop through it self and crash.